# Can I apply to grant as PI while I am postdoc in UK university?

Tags: postdocs, united-kingdom

I will start working as a postdoc at a university in the UK. I want to apply for a grant as PI and I am afraid to discuss this with my supervisor. Can I apply without telling him? The grant application goes through a university committee. So he will know anyway, but there is a high chance he wants to be PI on this grant and as it is my idea, I want to be the PI. I did not start working yet, so I don't know how this usually works in UK universities.
What should I do?

Comment: "I am afraid to discuss this with my supervisor." This is a major red flag. You should not be afraid of discussing this with your supervisor. In fact, you should not be afraid of them at all.

Comment: @Roland Of course this is a red flag, but sometimes working with a professor that has red flags can still bring certain advantages.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper They haven't even started the postdoc yet and are already afraid if their advisor? It seems likely the fear is unfounded. If it is actually reasonable, they should not start at this position and look for a better alternative.

Comment: I said I m afraid based on previous stories my colleaguestold me with different supervisors. I did not start yet with this supervisor.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to apply for/win grants as a Post-Doc in the UK, but it's rare. There are various independent fellowships which are intended for post-doc level applicants which are the more typical route to independence.

If you want to apply for this grant. First Make sure to evaluate if you even meet the criteria to apply as a PI. For example most [EPSRC grants this requires](https://www.ukri.org/councils/epsrc/guidance-for-applicants/check-if-you-are-eligible-for-funding/):

> Principal investigators should normally hold a permanent post but fixed-term employees may be eligible provided that the EPSRC can be satisfied that the host research organisation is prepared to give the individual all the support normal for a permanent employee and that there is no conflict of interest between the investigator’s obligations to the EPSRC and to any other organisation or employer.

(in practice this usually means at least holding an independent research fellowship - not being employed on someone else's grant).

Additionally, consider how realistic your chances of success are. Major grants are extremely competitive and have a very low success rate. One of the criteria for evaluating an application ([again from the EPSRC](https://epsrc.ukri.org/funding/assessmentprocess/review/formsandguidancenotes/standardcalls/)) is:

> a) Appropriateness of the track record of the applicant(s);
>
> - Whether the proposal demonstrates that the applicants have the
>   expertise and capabilities to deliver the project.
> - The applicant and wider team’s ability to deliver the project through
>   to the creation of impact.

(for example, experience successfully managing other grants).

Also do you have access to the necessary lab/software/resources to complete the project without the support of your PI?

I don't know your specific situation/qualifications, but in most cases you would have more success working with your PI to develop a grant application as a Co-PI. You can then learn from/take advantage of their experience/track record to increase the chances of success.

Comment: "in most cases you would have more success working with your PI to develop a grant application as a Co-PI." Can you explain why the success potential for a grant developed as Co-PI with the professor would be higher than that of an independent fellowship application on the same proposal idea?

Comment: @lighthousekeeper. 1) you can leverage the track record of the PI, 2) They evidently have experience writing successful grant applications, 3) They (presumably) have access to the necessary laboratory/administrative resources (and HoD support - which is a requirement to apply to most grants at UK universities).  An independent fellowship application would be the best way forward, but that is not what is being proposed by the OP.

Comment: For 1) and 3) The expectations towards the track record & available resources will probably be higher for a big grant than for an independent fellowship, so that one might neutralize itself, given that OP would only be Co-PI instead of PI in that case. In my experience, being able to collect money as PI weighs much more than Co-PI for later job applications.

Comment: 2.) - well, yes and no. Experience definitely helps, but the bulk of the effort for a grant application is still to develop the actual ideas. To benefit from others' experiences, one could seek external feedback (for example from other collaborators). Possibly also from grant counseling offices in the university. Finally, HoD support is potentially a valid argument. That one should be checked early - with HoD support it's a non-issue, without, that alternative doesn't exist in the first place.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper, Yes that's true. But the OP is not proposing to apply for an independent fellowship (which is what they should do if they want to be a PI). They seem to be proposing writing an application to an open call (apparently their supervisor wants to be PI on). Permanent faculty are not eligible to apply to independent post-doctoral fellowships in the UK. The OP is highly unlikely to even be eligible to apply for this grant as PI - Instead work with their supervisor as Co-PI, which would be better than no grant at all and a negative relationship with their supervisor.

Comment: It's not actually clear to me what grant OP intends to apply for (and a clarification would help). It's possible that he intends to go for a fellowship and is afraid that the professor might want to take the idea and become PI for it for in an open call application instead.

Comment: Agree that a clarification of what type of grant this is would be helpful. But if the PI wanted to steal their idea and apply for an open call with it there is unfortunately very little they could do about it. It also probably wouldn't prevent a fellowship application being successful on the same topic though (the committee probably wouldn't be aware of/permitted to discuss the other application).

Answer (score 3):

There are certain types of grants, usually with "fellowship" somewhere in the name (e.g. the Royal Society University Research Fellowship or the various Research Councils' Postdoctoral Fellowships), which are specifically designed for a postdoc to be the PI.  So the straight answer to the question in the title can only be "yes".

Answer (score 1):

You are a postdoc. You have to be independent. In your next Zoom call, or per email, simply state to your professor that you are writing a proposal as a PI for that grant. If you want to have a softer tone, state that you are *interested in* writing a proposal for that grant, and see how it goes.

Your professor may be in competition with you for that grant, but so he is with other hundreds of persons in the whole country, you have to have no guilty feelings.

The only possible negative point is that if your intention is to bring the money from that grant to a different department.

Comment: This is solid advice in the case of a PI that one might call *reasonable* - one that supports the development ambitions of their mentees, at the expense of winning fewer grants in their own name. Unfortunately, unreasonable PIs exist.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper there are conflicts that cannot be avoided, having a *unreasonable* supervisor is almost sure to lead to a conflict. However, the more such a supervisor is treated like a reasonable supervisor, the sooner the conflict will take place, with less damage for both sides. 
I repeat myself: there are conflicts that cannot be avoided, their outcome is loose-loose. However, it can be a big-loose - big-loose, or a small-loose - small-loose, depending on how and when the conflict starts. Since we are discussing a postdoc position here, it is better for the conflict to erupt at day1.

Comment: I don't know about other places, and it depends on the grant in question. But in the UK this is unlikely to be a successful strategy. There are a variety of independent fellowships which are designed for post-doc level candidates to gain independence. For major open grants, a post-doc would usually need to effectively be a permanent faculty member (or at least hold an independent fellowship and not be employed on someone else's grant). This advice runs the risk of negatively impacting the relationship with the PI with minimal prospect for success.

Comment: @EarlGrey The main drawback of the "early conflict" strategy that you propose is that the professor has the last word and, ultimately, might insist on his negative answer. An alternative strategy is to have the conflict as late as possible, at a point in time where one has already gained significant credits, so that the one negative experience (from the eyes of the professor) doesn't weigh as much.

Comment: Sadly this just does not make sense within the UK system... As stated with the answer above, a postdoc would not be eligible to apply to most UK funding streams as a PI (without some extraordinary support from his current institution: salary (as PI funding usually covers only about 20% of own salary), space, equipment). And also the advisor won't be eligible for the streams that are _targetting_ postdocs as PIs (usually called "fellowships").

Comment: (contd) So there is no competition in this situation. Also note that writing a proposal is hard work. I would strongly advise against the attitude of this answer "This is what I'll do, see if you can stop me". In order to write a solid fellowship proposal on top of the full-time postdoc position working on whichever project covers the postdoc salary, I would suggest looking for any support one can get. As one can't work 2+ times the regular hours and stay productive for long.

Comment: @penelope thanks. Please downvote the answer and make your comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its unlikely, but not impossible you will be able to apply for a grant as PI without the support of your institution, and they are unlikely to provide that without the support of the PI.

Most standard-type grants in the UK require you to have a permanent position at the host institution. Even in cases where this you argue an exception to this (see @atom44's answer), you will need the university to guarantee your employment for the period of the grant. Importantly, in the UK there is a cap on how much of a PI's salary a grant will pay. I can't remember off the top of my head, but i think it might be 40%. But its unusual for a grant to provide my than 20%. Someone has to agree to pay the rest.

Now, there is an alternative system to this: personal fellowships. Where as with a standard grant, thee grant is awarded to the university, with a fellowship its awarded to the individual. At least in my field there are two types of fellowship: postdoc level fellowships (such as the Henry Wellcome fellowship) and independent fellowships (e.g. the Wellcome Career Development fellowship, known until recently as the Sir Henry Dale fellowship).

With a postdoc fellowship, the grant is awarded to you, but to work under the close mentorship of someone else (i.e. your supervisor), so any application would need a letter of support from the proposed supervisor.

For an independent fellowship, you work independently (ie not with a supervisor). However, you still require support from the proposed host department. You will need not just permission from the head of department, but also the promise of real, concrete support both for the project itself, and your ongoing career development afterwards. My university promises a permanent faculty appointment to anyone completing an independent fellowship. Because of this the department has to make a business case to the university before supporting such an application. Its inconceivable all this could happen without your supervisor being aware.

Independent fellowships are highly prestigious, are generally longer than a standard grant (normally 5 years rather than 3) and come with about twice the level of funding support (around £1m-£2m). I don't know where you are in your career, but they are aimed at people with one or two postdoc positions already under their belt.